# Plot graph from the selected excel sheet

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

There are lot of csv excel sheets in a folder. All excel sheet contains data only in first 3 columns. I will select corresponding csv sheet from a lot of csv sheets and then plot it.Here is the code

```
import os
path = "F:\\Users\\Desktop\\Data\\Summary"
files = []
folder_data = os.listdir(path)
folder_data = [i+"\\" for i in folder_data]

# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.csv' in file:
            files.append(file)
for i, f in enumerate(files):
    print(( i,f))
    print('\n'.join(f'{i}-{v}' for i,v in enumerate(files)))
    csv_code = str(int(input("Enter corresponding code to plot: ")))
    csv_path = path + "\\" + folder_data[csv_code] 

    df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, header=None)
    df1 = df.iloc[:,0:2]
    plt.plot(df1[0], df1[1])
```

Currently only 1 csv sheet is displayed when i run code so When i run the code i want the Output to be displayed as follows (i mean i want all csv files from the folder to be displayed so that i can select what i want):

```
0-Test_Summary_1.csv
1-Test_Summary_2.csv
2-Test_Summary_3.csv
3-Test_Summary_4.csv
4-Test_Summary_5.csv
5-Test_Summary_6.csv etc
```

so that i select the corresponding code like 1 or 2 or 3 to plot.This is the error i am getting

```
    csv_path = path + "\\" + folder_data[csv_code]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Could you explain better what you want to achieve? Perhaps tell us what you are getting now?

Comment: Currently when i run program in the  output only 1 csv sheet is displayed in output.But i want all the csv sheet from the folder to be displayed in the output as said above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `input` call shouldn't be inside the `for` loop, because you want to print out all the items first. You can fix it as follows:

```
print('\n'.join(f'{i}-{v}' for i,v in enumerate(files))) # a shorter version of the loop

csv_code = int(input("Enter corresponding code to plot: "))
csv_path = os.path.join(path, files[csv_code])

df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, header=None)
df1 = df[0:2]
df1 = df.iloc[:,0:2]
plt.plot(df1[0], df1[1])
```

---

**Update**:

In your new code, you are casting `csv_code` to string for some reason. Firstly, `input()` will return a string, so there is no need to do `str(int(input()))`, and secondly, you require it to be a list index. So remove the `str` cast and leave it at `int(input())` as before.

Comment: When i run your modified code its correctly displaying all files from that folder but when i select the corresponding num to plot its not ploting

Comment: Print and check if `csv_path` is getting assigned the correct value as per your selection. As for the plotting error, please update your question with the new logs.

Comment: i will check it

Comment: csv_path = path + "\\" + folder_data[csv_code]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: I do not see that line in the code you've provided in your question. Please update your question by adding the relevant code and corresponding error to the bottom of the current question. Do not completely overwrite your previous question in the process.

Comment: Sorry , will update the code. Sir but please let me know why i am getting that error please

Comment: The error states that `folder_data` is a list, so you need to give it an integer index, while you are giving a string. However, you have casted `csv_code` to an `int` already. Also, where is `folder_data` defined in the current code? That is why I am asking you to update your code. I cannot help without the latest code.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please avoid using this single question for resolving all problems in your code. If you have any new problems, ask a new question. Since your original problem was solved, you can mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Sir, When i run now the updated code & select corresponding code to plot i am getting error as file not found error inspite of that file being there in the folder